# Android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2:Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android

This is  the XML file that is generating the error. Earlier it was working fine but then I modified the GUI i.e. this XMl file, without changing any core code,  and after that this error started coming.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/single_profile"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView android:id="@+id/name_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:textColor="#e600e5"/>


 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture_label"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/email_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#e600e5"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/artist_type_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#00b2b3"
        android:gravity="right"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/age_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#e600e5"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/country_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#00b2b3"
        android:gravity="right"/>


  <TextView android:id="@+id/description_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#e600e5"
        android:gravity="right"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/phone_no_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#00b2b3"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

  <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/like_label"
       android:layout_width="114dp"
       android:layout_height="38dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.04"
       android:textColor="#e600e5"
       android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_like"
       android:layout_width="50dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:background="@drawable/like_bg" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sms_label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Send SMS"
    android:textColor="#e600e5" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/call_label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Call"
    android:textColor="#e600e5" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace. But if I'd have to guess, your `single_profile` drawable is causing OutOfMemoryException. Make the image smaller to fix that.

Comment: and please post the related java class too

Comment: @laalto of course its not related to memory as you see he gets InflateException not OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Do you have the images in the drawable folder and colors.xml file in res folder..??

Comment: There's nested "caused by" exceptions for InflateExceptions.

Comment: yea maybe you are right

Comment: Try to setup crashlytics with fabric for free then you can see exception in detail.

Comment: Thanks... @laalto You were right...